# Exporting Flash Builder App to Blackberry OS

Tags: flash, blackberry, export, flash-builder

I am new to flash builder. I made an mobile app in Flash pro and it works fine on iOS/Android. I tried to export it to BB Playbook and I got a problem. I have all keys, certificates and software installed. I have read few tutorials about it, and I got an .swf in my project. It runs perfectly in simulator(Debug build). But when I build release build I get an empty .swf file inside the package. There is an .as file in the project with same name as .swf, which I guess is compiled to swf and replace it. Here is my project structure: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMoB1.png

How can I get my .swf instead of that .as file used? And why it works on debug build? All files are same.
Thank you for your help.

UPDATE: I have found tutorial I used. Here is the link: http://vimeo.com/23191894
It works for debug mode only. I tried to copy .SWF to src and bin-release folders, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you didn't selected your code for the release build.

I had the same problem with Code::Blocks, and I saw that I could check my source for debug and forget release.
I don't use Flash Builder, but you could search in source properties or the project properties.